# How can I create a real time search populate in real time with react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a real time search and real time populating users.

Here is how my page look like:
[image]

Right now my search function is I have to click search icon to make it appear the result so I want to change that to real time search. When I type the name in input it will auto starting appear the user card for me

Here is my code in SearchForMembers.js:

```
const SearchForMembers = ({ teamId, fetchTeamData }) => {
  // State
  const [userResults, setUserResults] = useState([]);
  const [userSkillResults, setUsersSkillsResults] = useState([]);

  const [showResultsList, setShowResultsList] = useState(false);
  const [showResultsMsg, toggleResultsMsg] = useState(false);

  // Submit search query
  const searchForTerm = async (term) => {
    try {
      if (term !== undefined) {
        // Clear results
        setUserResults([]);
        setUsersSkillsResults([]);
        // Perform search
        const res = await axios.get(`/api/v1/search/users/${term}`);
        // Check response
        // Show message if no results were found
        if (res.data[0].length === 0 && res.data[1].length === 0) {
          toggleResultsMsg(true);
        } else {
          toggleResultsMsg(false);
          // Set users results
          setUserResults(res.data[0]);
          // Set skills results
          setUsersSkillsResults(res.data[1]);
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userResults.length > 0 || userSkillResults.length > 0) {
      setShowResultsList(true);
    } else {
      setShowResultsList(false);
    }
  }, [userResults, userSkillResults]);

  return (
    <div className="container--search_for_members">
      {/* Search bar */}
      <SearchBar
        linkToPage={false}
        searchForTerm={searchForTerm}
        placeHolderText="Search for a name, skill or affiliation"
      />
      {/* Results list */}
      {showResultsList && (
        <SearchForMembersResults
          usersFound={userResults}
          userSkillResults={userSkillResults}
          teamId={teamId}
          fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
        />
      )}
      {showResultsMsg && (
        <>
          <p className="text--message-small">No results were found</p>
          <AddNewProfile
            teamId={teamId}
            fetchTeamData={fetchTeamData}
            variant="not in table"
          />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is my code in SearchBar,js :

```
const SearchBar = ({
  linktoPage,
  searchForTerm,
  placeHolderText = "Search members or teams",
}) => {
  // Search state
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // Update state with input text
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    try {
      event.preventDefault();

      if (linktoPage) {
        // Go to page and pass query
        goToPage();
      } else {
        // Don't change pages, but pass term to search method
        searchForTerm(searchTerm);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };

  const goToPage = () => {
    // Go to search page and pass along the search term.
    Router.push({
      pathname: "/search",
      query: { term: `${searchTerm}` },
    });
  };

  return (
    <form className="form--search_wrapper" method="GET" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        className="input input--search_input"
        type="search"
        name="q"
        placeholder={placeHolderText}
        aria-label="Search bar"
        onInput={handleChange}
        pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"
        required
      />
      <Button className="input input--search" style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: "#00B790" }} type="submit" >
        <SearchRoundedIcon />
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

I read about the live search with axios. Here is the link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-live-search-with-axios

How can I use .filter in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call the body of your handleSubmit function in the handleChange function, you probably want to debounce it so you don't call your api for every keystroke though

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // Update state with input text
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    try {   
      if (linktoPage) {
        // Go to page and pass query
        goToPage();
      } else {
        // Don't change pages, but pass term to search method
        searchForTerm(event.target.value);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: So I don't need form anymore ?

Comment: no, you don't need to submit the form, but you might want it to remove the autocomplete for exemple